# Imprimir resultado de un script en un input

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios

Quiero convertir lo del primer cuadro de texto a mayuscula y minuscula, según yo esta bien mi función pero no se como hacer que se imprima el resultado en el cuadro de texto de abajo.
Cada que doy click en el boton se recarga la pagina y se borra el texto del recuadro

```js
function mayus() {
    var resultado
    var inicio
    var inicio = document.getElementById('original');
    var resultado = inicio.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById('resultado'.innerHTML = resultado)
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        <p>
            Bienvenido
        </p>
        <p>
            La página que estás viendo requiere para su funcionamiento el uso de JavaScript. Si lo has deshabilitado intencionadamente,
            por favor vuelve a activarlo.
        </p>
    </noscript>
    <form name="formulario" id="inicial">
        <input type="text" id="original"/><br>
        <input type="text" id="resultado" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="MAYUSCULA" onclick="mayus()" ><br>
        <input type="submit" value="minuscula">
    </form> 
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Pagina]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisando te identifico que:

1) No hace nada porque la variable `inicio` no estaba guardando el value(valor) de la caja de texto

2) En mi particular yo asigno el valor directo al elemento HTML no uso append

```
function mayus() {
    var resultado
    var inicio
    var inicio = document.getElementById('original').value;
    var resultado = inicio.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById('resultado').value= resultado;
};
```

3) los submit deben ser botones

```
<input type="button" value="MAYUSCULA" onclick="mayus()" ><br>
```

4) Por si lo quieres;

```
function minus() {
    var resultado
    var inicio
    var inicio = document.getElementById('original').value;
    var resultado = inicio.toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById('resultado').value= resultado;
};

<input type="button" value="minuscula" onclick="minus()">
```

Comment: Solucionado muchas gracias :)